# Term for a magma with a left identity?

Tags: magma

Is there a term for a magma $(M,*)$ that contains at least one left identity element, but not necessarily a right identity element? I'm looking for a term that requires only
$$\exists e \in M \text{ such that},\, \forall a \in M,\, e*a = a.$$

Comment: I guess it could be called a left-unital magma. I don't know if there's a more standard name.

Comment: There is no standard term for these magmas.